# Golang, GOPATH not set error

Tags: go

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run the go code:

```
cannot find package "github.com/drone/routes" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/github.com/drone/routes (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the FAQs for Go - it is in there.

Answer (score 2):

Well it is saying that your GOPATH is not set. I would suggest taking a look at the [Go docs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable) to get that configured.

Answer (score 2):

Set under the Windows:
open cmd

```
C:\Users\zhg>set GOPATH=C:\PATH

C:\Users\zhg>echo %GOPATH%
>>> C:\PATH
```

Set under the Linux:
open bash

```
zhg@ubuntu:~$ export GOPATH=$HOME/path
zhg@ubuntu:~$ echo $GOPATH 
>>> /home/zhg/path
```

Looking all go environment:
`$ go env`

Set forever, you need to edit the environment files.